# Qt QAbstractItemModel dropped data signal

Tags: c++, qt

I have a model derived from `QAbstractItemModel` and I implemented Drag&Drop functionality via MIME types (via overriding of `QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData()...`).

**Short Version/TLDR;**

My question is: Is there some signal that `QAbstractItemModel` emits when MIME data handling is fully complete?

***Long Version***

When a user reorders a model item via drag&drop, there are some adjustments I need to do in other Views. For this reason, I created a custom signal that I emit right at the end of my override of `QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData()`. HOWEVER, when this signal is emited, the moved items have not yet been really moved: they have been copied, but the old items have not yet been removed; hence, I have duplicated and unordered items.

Comment: Is it important that the reordering occurs using drag and drop? `QAbstractItemModel` emits signals when items are moved are inserted.

Comment: How is your `dropMimeData` implemented?

Comment: @m7913d I checked a while ago that, despite  `QAbstractItemModel` has some `move...()` related function prototypes, they don't work and I checked in Qt 5.7 that this is true. So my `dropMimeData` is implemented by serialise my items to XML in `mimeData()` and then copying them in `dropMimeData`. The old item removal is handled by Qt when `dropMimeData`returns true.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `...Moved` should be emitted. Note that if you create a custom `QAbstractItemModel`, you should implement `move...` yourself and call `beginMove...` before you start moving your data and `endMove...` after you moved your data. You should also call these methods if you perform a move using `dropMimeData`.

Comment: Note that you can also use the [default drop implementation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#drag-and-drop-support-and-mime-type-handling) (see Accepting dropped data) of  `QAbstractItemModel`, which implements the move as an insert and a remove.

Comment: @m7913d Do you know of any example?

Comment: [This puzzle example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-puzzle-example.html) may be what you are looking for.